# How can I create and query against temp table in HiveQL?

Tags: hive, odbc, hiveql

I am new to HiveQL and I need to create a temp table from the results of following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` LIMIT 0,100;
```

....Then run query against this temp table. How could I accomplish this and what is the best practice?

So i guess the SQL Anywhere version would be something like:

```
create table #temp (foo int)
insert into #temp (foo)
select top (100) 1
from dbo.table t
select count(*) from #temp as c
drop table #temp
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In hive you can create similar functionality using `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` . Table can me managed or external and will stay as long as your hive session is active. Also, pls note, if you are running it as part of batch process, this may not be a good idea.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE etl.tmp1 as select * from  tab  limit 10;
select count(*) from  etl.tmp1 ;
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for answering!  the driver my client is using didn't love the 'top' statement.
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS SELECT * FROM `foodmart`.`salary` LIMIT 0,100;

I created the table I needed using this query,  how could i just return a count(8) from this temp table now?

If I do something like this:

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS SELECT * FROM `foodmart`.`salary` LIMIT 0,100;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp;

I receive this error:

SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 missing EOF at 'Select' near '100'

Comment: i corrected my sql. i think there is some issue with your sql.  Are you running using hue or command task or some tool? put a new line between first and second statement. You can see how i ran it in the answer.

Comment: I am using DBeaver.

Comment: The link at the top is the query i ran in DBeaver and the Error returned.

Comment: Can you try just with `limit 100`? Remove 0,.

Comment: Thank you so much @Koushik Roy.  This all helped a lot.